# React-native 1D barcode generator

Tags: react-native, generator, barcode

I was looking for react-native module to integrate barcode generator for 1D barcodes. I know I can scan the barcodes with various modules, but what about generating scanned codes? 
Only thing I could come up was generating QR and Aztec codes, but those are not 1D barcodes. Can someone help me with this problem? 
I also thought about if I scan the code in react-native code, send that information to other application running in the back, which generates SVG barcode image for example and send the location to react-native app to find it in the resources. Everything should be run locally. Would something like that be possible?

Thank you for all the help and replies,
Domen

Answer (score 1):

This library now exists: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-barcode-builder

I created [a pull request](https://github.com/wonsikin/react-native-barcode-builder/pull/2) to add the other formats from JsBarcode and we're using it to generate EAN barcodes in our react native application.

In terms of using an external service to generate the barcodes and displaying them in the application, that's certainly possible, but for something as simple as this I think it'd be ideal if your application generated the barcodes by itself without a dependency on an external service.